# Rspec mocks error: wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby, rspec, stripe-payments

I'm trying to stub out the Stripe API using Rspec and I'm running into an issue. Here's what my code looks like:

```
Stripe::Customer.should_receive(:create).with(any_args).and_raise(Stripe::CardError)
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
Failure/Error: Stripe::Customer.should_receive(:create).with(any_args).and_raise(Stripe::CardError)
ArgumentError:
  wrong number of arguments (0 for 3..6)
```

Comment: Does Stripe::CardError require 3..6 arguments by any chance?

Comment: I think it might, but I was under the impression Rspec would do a little magic to create an mocked instance of the error. Is that not the case?

Comment: I'm not aware of that capability, but it wouldn't have a chance to anyway, since Ruby is going to evaluate Strip::CardError before RSpec has a chance to do anything.

Comment: Downvote seems a little harsh. Finding wrong number of argument errors in a chained call in a test case where you've got both the test code and the running code in a language that doesn't require parentheses for method calls can be confusing.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Stripe::CardError requires 3..6 arguments, per the following source code:

```
class CardError < StripeError
  ...
  def initialize(message, param, code, http_status=nil, http_body=nil, json_body=nil)
```

Here's the key documentation from the RSpec doc at github:

```
expect(double).to receive(:msg).and_raise(error)
  #error can be an instantiated object or a class
  #if it is a class, it must be instantiable with no args
```

Since you're just providing the class and the class requires arguments, it's failing. You need to instantiate it (i.e. via `new`) and provide arguments.

Full definition is in https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby/blob/0c281891948a793e79cc997d31918ba7f987f7ae/lib/stripe/errors/card_error.rb

Comment: Simple enough. Thanks for the help.

Comment: This answer helped me discover that I couldn't write something like `expect(obj).to receive(:msg).and_raise(ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)`. I had to pass the record to the error. `expect(obj).to receive(:msg).and_raise(ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid.new(obj))`. The stacktrace and message returned from RSpec of `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)` didn't make it apparent that it was the error message not being initialized properly. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @KyleTolle thank you for that. I've been banging my head on this since lunch.

Comment: @KyleTolle I had the exact same problem. I wonder if RSpec should be better at highlighting these problems...

Comment: @JacoPretorius Yes, it would be very helpful if RSpec would tell you the problem, or at least give some sort of hint. Part of the problem would be that it depends on the error message being used. Not all errors require an object at instantiation. For me, it was an issue of not being familiar with the `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid` error enough to know it required an object. Knowing _which_ method call needed an argument would have been more helpful. Otherwise you have to know the internals of `and_raise` to know that's where the error might be coming from. Tricky to find out!

Comment: I had the same issue raising `Aws::S3::Errors::NoSuchKey` which requires request and response arguments and I'm not about to recreate for this test.

`.and_raise(Aws::S3::Errors::NoSuchKey.new(nil, nil))` worked for me tho!